# HTTPS over WebSockets tunnel

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, cryptography

I'm trying to build a system in which the backend can send request to the client that will behave as a proxy. I'm constrained in using WebSockets due to the current state of the remote server. I've build a basic version of my idea that works with HTTP request sent from a browser, but as soon as I activate HTTPS it apparently fails on the handshake. I'm adding a request ID to organise and imitate the request/response model. I want to achieve an E2E encryption with this proxy chain.

This is my code for the proxy that catches the requests and sends them over the WebSocket:

```
const net = require('net');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const crypto = require("crypto");

const wss = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001');
const server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
  
  // settings per connection opened
  let requests = [];

  // Receives data
  socket.on('data', data => {
    const requestID = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");

    const additionalInfo = JSON.stringify({
      "Request": requestID,
    });
    
    const header = Buffer.from(`${additionalInfo.length} ${additionalInfo}\n\n`);
    wss.send(Buffer.concat([header, data]));
    requests.push(requestID);
  });

  socket.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  socket.on('end', () => {
    requests = [];
  });

  // server response to the request
  wss.on('message', (data) => {

    // extract basic data
    const jsonDataSize = data.toString().split(' ')[0];
    const jsonDataOffset = jsonDataSize.length + 1;
    
    const jsonDataText = data.slice(jsonDataOffset, Number(jsonDataSize) + jsonDataOffset).toString();
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonDataText);
    
    const message = data.slice(Number(jsonDataSize) + jsonDataOffset + 2);
    
    // check if received response matches the request
    if (requests.includes(jsonData.Request)) {
      // console.log(data.toString());

      socket.write(message);
    }
  });

  wss.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});

server.on('close', () => {
  console.log("Server closed");
})

server.listen({host: "localhost", port: 8000}, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on localhost:8000");
});
```

This is my code for the WebSocket receiver:

```
const net = require('net');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8001}, () => {
  console.log('WebSocket server listening on localhost:8001');
});

wss.on('connection', socket => {
  let server;

  // trigger for a new message from the same connection
  socket.on('message', data => {

    // console.log("---------->");
    // console.log(data.toString());

    const jsonDataSize = data.toString().split(' ')[0];
    const jsonDataOffset = jsonDataSize.length + 1;

    const jsonDataText = data.slice(jsonDataOffset, Number(jsonDataSize) + jsonDataOffset).toString();

    // check if it is a new tls connection request
    let isTLSConnection = data.toString().indexOf("CONNECT") !== -1;

    // set the new connection's settings
    if (isTLSConnection && data.toString().includes('Host: ')) {
      const  serverPort = 443;
      const serverAddress = data
        .toString()
        .split("CONNECT")[1]
        .split(" ")[1]
        .split(":")[0];

      server = net.createConnection({host: serverAddress, port: serverPort});

      // Send back 200 OK to the browser
      const header = Buffer.from(`${jsonDataSize} ${jsonDataText}\n\n`);
      socket.send(Buffer.concat([header, Buffer.from("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n")]));

      return;
    } else if (data.toString().includes('Host: ')) {
      const  serverPort = 80;
      const serverAddress = data.toString().split('Host: ')[1].split("\r\n")[0];

      server = net.createConnection({host: serverAddress, port: serverPort});
    }

    // extract payload
    const message = data.slice(Number(jsonDataSize) + jsonDataOffset + 2);

    // send payload to server
    server.write(message);

    server.on('data', (data) => {
      // console.log("<----------");
      // console.log(data.toString());

      const header = Buffer.from(`${jsonDataSize} ${jsonDataText}\n\n`);

      socket.send(Buffer.concat([header, data]));
    });

    server.on('error', error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });

  socket.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

I took inspiration from [Build your own proxy server from scratch](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/build-your-own-forward-and-reverse-proxy-server-using-node-js-from-scratch-eaa0f8d69e1f)

I tried implementing a request/response model on top of WebSockets since I believe the error relies there, but it didn't work

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I get: An error occurred: SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ

Answer (score 0):

You should use **wss**://localhost:8001 when using https

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem/error message. Since the WebSocket server dosnt even listen for TLS connections you would produce just a error more.